# HttpsUrlConnection Does not Support SetRequestMethod?

Tags: android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

I wrote a code to establish an `HttpsUrlConnection` and `setRequestMethod` as `PUT`. While debugging I see the method as `GET`. My `SetRequestMethod` is not working. I don't know why `HttpsUrlConnection` method in default `GET`.

**My code looks like this**

```
DisbleSSL disble = new DisbleSSL();

disble.disableSSLVerification();

URL url = new URL(url_string);

httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

httpsUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

httpsUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

httpsUrlConnection.connect();
```

Comment: I think u should use HttpURLConnection not HttpsURLConnection.

Comment: I am trying to upload cloud.that needs HttpsUrlConnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpsUrlConnection definitely support setrequestMethod.Actually but it may be Wrong Labled in Debugg console.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4iqV.png)

HttpsURLConnection use internal objects ->
protected DelegateHttpsURLConnection delegate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try setRequestMethod before setDoOutput

Comment: That would actually set it to POST.